# Java 8 Stream if not execute collect function then filter and map function not work

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");

    // below code does not work
    list.stream().filter(new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            System.out.println("1：test：" + s);
            return true;
        }
    }).map(s -> {
        System.out.println("1：map：" + s);
        return s;
    });
    
    // below code works
    list.stream().filter(new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            System.out.println("2：test" + s);
            return true;
        }
    }).map(s -> {
        System.out.println("2：map" + s);
        return s;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The output of the above code is：

```
2：test1
2：map1
2：test2
2：map2
2：test3
2：map3
2：test4
2：map4
```

I don't know why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: Streams are lazily evaluated.

Comment: The first stream will not be evaluated at all, because it doesn't have a terminal operation.

Comment: Why do you use a verbose anonymous inner class creation for the predicates when you know about lambda expressions, as shown with the map functions?

Answer (score 1):

The `doSomething` in the lambda `p -> doSomething(p)` would be called only when the lambda is executed. The simple presence of that statement does not guarantee execution, whereas a normal (not a lambda) statement  `doSomething(x)` guarantees execution.

`map` and `filter` are intermediate operations, whereas `collect` is a terminal operation. For each intermediate operation, a new stream object (any implementation of `Stream` like `StatelessOp`, `StatefulOp` or primitive specialization of streams like `IntStream`, `LongStream` etc.)  is returned, which stores any information like the mapping or filtering function as in your case. Actual execution does not happen here.

Stream evaluation happens with the invocation of `evaluate` method. Now, if you see any terminal operation, it would invoke this `evaluate` method. This is were the lambdas you pass as argument to the intermediate operations are applied to the stream elements. That is why streams are said to be lazily evaluated -> Evaluation only starts with application of a terminal operation.

Hence you first code block does not work, because there are no terminal operations, and the lambdas you passed are not executed. But in the second code block you call a terminal operation and stream is evaluated. Also note that the intermediate operation need not be executed for every stream element -> [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67669583/7804477)

You could see the implementation of each stream method in `ReferencePipeline`.

Answer (score 0):

> A stream pipeline consists of a source (which might be an array, a
> collection, a generator function, an I/O channel, etc), zero or more
> intermediate operations (which transform a stream into another stream,
> such as filter(Predicate)), and a terminal operation (which produces a
> result or side-effect, such as count() or forEach(Consumer)). Streams
> are lazy; computation on the source data is only performed when the
> terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only
> as needed.

[Read more here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Comment: But I want to understand how Stream is implemented lazy