# How to use stream to filter objects from HashSet that have empty value for certain fields?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I am looking for a way to filter only the Worker objects with a specific first name and empty lastName from the given `HashSet`. For example I want the code to return the record with `firstName == scott and lastName == ""`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Worker w1 = new Worker("scott","tiger");
    Worker w2 = new Worker("panthera","tigris");
    Worker w3 = new Worker("scott","");
    Worker w4 = new Worker("alpha","romeo");
    Worker w5 = new Worker("apple","orange");
    Set<Worker> wset = new HashSet<>();
    wset.add(w1);
    wset.add(w2);
    wset.add(w3);
    wset.add(w4);
    wset.add(w5);
    System.out.println(wset.stream().filter(worker -> worker.firstName == "scott" && --something on these lines??--)); // ???
}
```

Comment: ....`&& worker.lastName.isEmpty()` and you need a terminal operation also after filtering eg: `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` or `.findFirst()` to get first item.

Comment: Also, how can I include null safety before I call " .stream() " on the collection object?

Comment: You don't need to filter before `.stream()` you can filter after `.stream()` same way for null items in set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` is a non-terminal operation and the stream would be processed only when a terminal operation is encountered. [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68103822/7804477)

So you may use `collect` to display the filtered elements. Also use `equals` to compare strings instead of `==`. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```java
wset.stream()
    .filter(worker -> worker.firstName.equals("scott") 
                      && worker.lastName.isBlank()); // use isEmpty() instead of isBlank if java version is below 11.
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you want to do "*null safety before I call " .stream() " on the collection object*" then you could use `Stream.ofNullable` (since java 9)

```java
Stream.ofNullable(wset)
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      // rest of the code from above snippet
```